# Resolve azure policy sql server should use customer managed keys to encrypt for bicep script

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-bicep, tde

The following bicep script should create a SQL Server. However, due to Azure policy violation it fails, and requires that I use customer-managed keys to encrypt data. See Error:

[image]

Here's the code block to encrypt protection for SQL Server. Still getting the error above (not sure why it won't work):

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' = {
  location: location
  name: name
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: adminUsername
    administratorLoginPassword: adminPassword
    publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccess
  }
}

resource encryptProtectSQLServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/encryptionProtector@2021-11-01' =  {
  name: 'current'
  parent: sqlServer
  properties: {
    autoRotationEnabled: true
    serverKeyName: 'key-adf-cdis-devtest-va'
    serverKeyType: 'AzureKeyVault'
  }
}
```

When I add keyId:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' = {
  location: location
  name: name
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: adminUsername
    administratorLoginPassword: adminPassword
    publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccess
    keyId: 'https://kvinfratestva.vault.usgovcloudapi.net/keys/key-pcr-sqlserver/654aa7c96d51450cassaassa15fce3ff26'
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is that you need to give the SQL Server RBAC permission to the KeyVault via a RoleAssignment. I personally prefer a User Assigned Managed Identity as it can be independently lifecycled (created in advance of your SQL Server by someone with permissions if your organisation has a tight security policy).

> By default, TDE in Azure SQL uses the primary user-assigned managed
> identity set on the server for key vault access. If no user-assigned
> identities have been assigned to the server, then the system-assigned
> managed identity of the server is used for key vault access. When
> using a user-assigned managed identity for TDE with CMK, assign the
> identity to the server and set it as the primary identity for the
> server
>
> The primary user-assigned managed identity requires continuous
> key vault access (get, wrapKey, unwrapKey permissions). If the
> identity's access to key vault is revoked or sufficient permissions
> aren't provided, the database will move to Inaccessible state

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-identity?view=azuresql#considerations-while-using-umi-for-customer-managed-tde

---

The second issue you could have is if the KeyVault is firewalled to only accept connections from connected Virtual Networks. I notice that you're using the US Gov Cloud (usgovcloudapi.net). So you could be might well have fun here given this restriction.

> The Allow Trusted Microsoft Services to bypass this firewall option is
> currently not available in National clouds.

Good luck!